# Stop excel from converting copy-pasted number/text values to date

Tags: html, microsoft-excel, import, copy-paste

I'm copy-pasting some data from html table into excel. But excel automatically converts some text or number values to date! When I change the format, the number is perversed, the number is something like 4112523 (excel probably interprets the cell as date and then converts to number or something like that...)

[There is a trick for importing CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/165042/684229), but is there any solution when you are pasting your data directly from a web browser?

Comment: Have you tried custom formula?

Comment: Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13082641/1370465

Comment: @JeremyJohn - custom formula? What do you mean?

Comment: but the data you are pasting is not about dates, right?

Comment: @BrOSs - exactly

Comment: what about a working-aroung? it can be silly but what if you paste it in notepad?

Comment: can you show example of data you are inserting into excel?

Comment: The fact that any software thinks the most appropriate way to behave is to assume you want it to reformat whatever information you gave it because surely you didn't mean for it to be THAT way... with no easy and obvious way to disable it... is the single dumbest design decision and annoying thing about Excel. I should not have click through an import wizard if all I am trying to do is copy/paste from one CSV to another. The friggin thing is a number in one CSV. Why on God's green earth would I want it to paste a date? What idiot designed that?

Comment: *Before* pasting, format the whole sheet as text.  Now, the data you paste will not be reformatted or even analyzed for you in any way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it worked out for me:

> Data - Import external data - New web query and follow the wizard

It's so simple.

regards!

Comment: thank you, nice tip! But it still converts the fields...

Comment: I have found an import option "Disable Date Recognition" that did the trick!! So this (the import) is the only way that works for me!

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this works only when copy-pasting from a web source. If it is copy pasting from MS Access for example, this is unusable.

Comment: The import external data worked for me too with MS Access, you just look for the .mdb source file. Are you working with office 2007+ ?

Comment: Yes, but this is complicated - it is much more comfortable to mark the rows you want in Access... I have office 2003

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't address copy/pasting at all.

Answer (score 39):

This is definately a kluge and it's the only thing I've figured out to do. I came here looking for a more elegant solution.

I do have a slight improvement for this.

1. Paste the data into the spreadsheet as is.
2. Select all and format as text
3. Paste again over what you did the first time but this time as values.

This keeps you from having to count columns and rows, etc.

If you have data you actually want to be numbers, dates, etc, it's much easier to reformat them correctly from this end than it is to do from the other. Since the numbers won't automatically convert, I used text to columns on the column, selecting "delimited" but unchecking all the delimiters. This has the same effect as going into each cell and hitting enter to get Excel to recognize it again. Ugly, but it works.

Comment: The real trick is that the cells must be formatted to **text** beforehand. The first paste helps identifying which cells are going to be covered afterwards. Good advice!

Comment: Caution: Padded numbers, such as "00001", lose their padding. These are converted to 1 and than to "1". The original number is unrecoverable. Tibo's solution works nicely.

Comment: MS advices the same: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8

Comment: Note: Does not work from Word.  Does work from Notepad.

Answer (score 23):

The Most simple way.

```
1. Copy the original Data
2. Paste to Notepad (Prefer Notepad++)
3. Change the Cell Properties to TEXT
4. Copy All from Notepad
5. Paste back to Excel.
```

Comment: OK, so for million cells you do it million times?

Comment: U can select the whole column from the top. It will select all, and copy and paste to the notepad.

Comment: This works! you can even just start at step 3!  Select the whole sheet, format as text, paste! done.

Comment: This is what I end up doing because just changing the data to text within Excel doesn’t always work, e.g. if you have some ‘text’ that happens to be a long number (product codes etc.), Excel displays it in scientific notation.

Comment: Excel is stupid. WHY DO THEY DO THIS TO US??? However, your solution is the only one that consistently works.

Comment: this works for me, thanks

Answer (score 11):

Before pasting, select column that will hold the non-date value. Right click. Select 'format cells'. Then select 'text' as the format and click OK.

Now, go ahead and paste, but paste using the 'match the destination formatting' option.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: For formatting, "Text" works and "General" doesn't work. The detail I missed. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open a Blank Workbook
2. Click on Data
3. Click From Text
4. Locate your CSV/txt file
5. Click Next
6. Choose your Delimiter
7. Click Next
8. Use the scroll bar to locate the column you wish to protect and click on it
9. Select Text from the Column data format
10. Click Finish
11. Click OK

The data will now have been imported without the date conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Select all the cells, and change their format to Text.

Then choose Paste -> Match Destination Formatting.

Answer (score 1):

options/Transition

transition formula evaluation - enable it

PS

and forget about already pasted and saved data. =(

Comment: Great! This works! Unfortunatelly, it perverses other data... there is a date in another column in the form "01/05/1998" and it computes 0,0001001 out of it :-) :-(

Comment: And it should be "transition formula entry" instead.. and note that this option is per sheet..

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a kluge, but if the data can be pasted normally (without using Paste Special) it usually works:

1. Format all empty cells where dates will fall as text.
2. Right-click when pasting and select "Match destination formatting."

Be careful, though, b/c if you paste numbers into the cells that you've pre-formatted, they will also be converted to text, and you'll have to use value() or such to get them back (with Excel 2013 you get a preview of where the data will go just be hovering over the Paste button, so I usually do that and then convert the columns where date-like strings will land first).

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following options :

1) Select the cells and go to Format --> cells --> number and select Text for the selection

OR

2) While pasting it from MS word paste it using Paste Special option and select 'Values only" option in the dialog box

Comment: 1) doesn't work - the number is already perversed when I change format to text. 2) doesn't work - Paste Special does not contain the standard offer, but only: HTML, text in Unicode, text. Because I'm pasting html content.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your internet browser, File/Save Page as/Save As-Webpage, Complete/"name it"
2. Open Excel (2007), File/Open/"name it" File you saved in #1

Answer (score 0):

Extension of Alex Robilotto's [Answer](https://superuser.com/a/784991/647254) for clipboard object *not* formatted as "text".

- E.g., this works for **web-based clipboard objects**

The steps:

```
1. Paste the data into the spreadsheet as is.
2. Select all and format the cells as text
3. Paste original clipboard object again over what you did the first time
   - But this time select "Paste Special..." and select "Text".
```

<sup>Note: pasting *as value* is not an option for non-text, web-based clipboard object.</sup>